Dynamic parameters in a parameterized query AWS wrangler
I am attempting to parameterize my existing SQL code using aws data wrangler, however, I was unable to find any documentation to help in creating a variable number of dynamic parameters. For example, I want to parameterize the code below where the txn_types can be an array of multiple values like ['In'] or ['In', 'Out', 'Transfer']. How would I be able to create a variable list of placeholders denoted with a ?.
What I tried:

I am thinking of an approach to use the length of the array to create a placeholder list. But was unsure of best practices with parameterized queries and how I can make it work.

If anyone has suggestions, I would love to hear them!
def add_group_transaction_type_constraint(params: dict[str, Union[str, list]]) -> str:
   txn_types = params.get("group_transaction_types")
    
    return (
        f" AND groupTransactionType IN ({txn_types})"
        if txn_types
        else ""
    )

